# PL/pgSQL procedure not executed

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am testing a very simple stored procedure in PostgreSQL. The code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2()
   RETURNS trigger AS
   $BODY$
   DECLARE
       record DOUBLE PRECISION;
   BEGIN
       SELECT value into record from sensorlastdatalog where sensor_id = 1;
       record = record / 100000;
       INSERT INTO kpihistdatalog(id, kpi_id, controlelement_id, logdate, valuedate, value)
          VALUES (nextval('kpihistdatalog_id_seq'), 1, 0, now(), now(), record);
   RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

And the trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER kpi_calc_test
AFTER INSERT
ON sensorlastdatalog
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test2();
```

However, when I check the `kpihistdatalog` table, no new inserts are there. I have checked that the `sensorlastdatalog` and it had been updated. I guess I am doing something wrong, could you help me, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider adding `raise notice` statements in the trigger to first check if it's executed or not. There's nothing apparently wrong per se in the code shown.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance of not knowing where to see these notices, but I have not widely worked with PL/pgSQL. So, where could I see the messages, if any? Thanks a lot

Comment: what is your client? The most simply way is run SQLs from `psql` console, and there you can see notices directly. In pgAdminIII is in SQL Query editor a tab "messages".

Comment: Ok! Thanks, I was not executing the procedure "by hand". Now, I have done it and it is a error message: [ERROR    ] 4.0-5: syntax error, unexpected character. However, the queries are tested and they work.